# CSS package for fullscreen fluid, responsive layout, scrolling content

Tags: css, layout, fluid

I am looking for a CSS package that will aid one in building a fluid/responsive layout with scrolling content... I don't know if I'm describing this accurately, but what I mean is represented well [here](http://bklynsoap.com/) and [here](https://mylapka.com/).

there are others, but those 2 show it well enough.

Any tips to that?  Am I overthinking things, and it's as simple as one big column-less CSS grid (i.e. I could even use twitter's Bootstrap as a starting place)?  I've tried some simplistic designs with this, but it never seems to work for every device / every time I resize the screen.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Is this the expression you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design?

Comment: twitter bootsrap is a good choice imo. I often use it as a strating point for a responsive design. It works well and there is a lot of info available. Note that you can remove the stuff you don't need on the customize tab, or even download the less files and edit those and compile your own version.

Answer (score 0):

When doing responsive design, you'll want to make sure you set a meta tag to viewport initial-scale value of 1. Mobile devices tend to pack more pixel values into actual pixels so that they fit on the screen, but if you set the viewport's initial-scale value to 1 then you're essentially telling the device you want the page to be viewed on at a 1 to 1 pixel ratio.

Add this to your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
```